# What does this one liner means in lambda function in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, lambda

I'm stuck in this lambda one-liner. This one-liner is for sorting the string in a list but don't know how this actually functions? Kindly help me to understand this.
This is the motive of the below function:

sort_item_list_by_author(): Accepts the new list of books and returns it sorted in the alphabetical order of their author names. Note: While sorting the author names in alphabetical order, ignore the special characters including space, if there are any.

```
    def sort_item_list_by_author(self,new_item_list):
       new_item_list.sort(key=lambda x:''.join(e for e in x.get_author_name() if e.isalnum())) #problem causing line

    item11=Item("Broken Wing","Sarojini Naidu",2012)
    item12=Item("Guide","R.K.Narayanan",2001)
    item13=Item("Indian Summers","John Mathews",2001)
    item14=Item("Innocent in Death","J.D.Robb",2010)
    item15=Item("Life of Pi","Yann Martel",2010 )
    item16=Item("Sustainability","Johny",2016)
    item17=Item("Look Ahead","E.M.Freddy",2012 )

    new_item_list=[item11,item12,item13,item14,item15,item16,item17]
    new_item_list_sorted=library.sort_item_list_by_author(new_item_list)
```

Comment: What aspect of that line confuses you?

Comment: whats the difference between the above one liner and this line- new_item_list.sort(key=lambda x:x.get_author_name())?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica i can't understand from join

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lambda you are talking about is the key to the sort function, which means that it is being you used to compare the values in the list.

> `lambda x:''.join(e for e in x.get_author_name() if e.isalnum()`

So for every element of the list, this lambda function is called. Here `x` represents the parameter of the lambda function(in this case, it is list item). 
Now the body of the lambda function is pretty simple in itself, we get the author name, and loop over it character by character, and select only those characters which are alpha-numeric(means we are ignoring spaces and all), then we join all the obtained chars in one string.

Using the lambda function, for all the items in the list, such strings(alpha-num part of author's name) are created, which is used for sorting out the list.
The lambda translates to something like this:

```
x = item() #fill the fields here
s = ''
for e in x.get_author_name():
    if e.isalnum():
       s += e
```

Comment: but why we are seeing alphanumeric, as we can sort the author names simply by fetching the author name of every list item?

Comment: because without alphanumeric condition, you will have `BWriter`  in front of `A. Writer` , which shouldn't happen. So we have that condition to ignore spaces, dots etc.

Comment: so you mean we have to ignore dots also along with the spaces? Ok, if yes then can you please break this one-liner into the beginner level piece of code?

Comment: You have mentioned in your question that we have to ignore special characters.

Comment: Ok, kindly break this one-liner into more understandable code for the beginners like us.

Comment: is item() a tuple or a set? but can we use a list and then add the elements?

Comment: `Item` is the class that you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, lambda is a keyword used to define anonymous functions(functions with no name) and that's why they are known as lambda functions.Let's see an example.

```py
>>> addition=lambda x1,x2:x1+x2  
>>> subtraction=lambda x1,x2:x1-x2
>>> addition(10,20)
30
>>> subtraction(10,20)
-10
>>> #there is another way also
>>>(lambda num1, num2: num1+num2)(10,20)
30
```

Now Suppose we have a list of items(integers and strings with numeric contents)

```
numbers = [1,"2", "5", 3, 4, "8", "-1", "-11"]
```

Now I am using sorted function to sort it, You can use sort also but as we know sort function alters the original data but the sorted returns a new sorted list

```
>>> numbers = [1,"2", "5", 3, 4, "8", "-1", "-11"]
>>> sorted(numbers)
[1, 3, 4, '-1', '-11', '2', '5', '8']
>>>
```

But this is not expected answer

```
['-11', '-1', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5', '8']
```

so here we've to used to key keyword as a argument

```
>>> sorted(numbers, key=int)
['-11', '-1', 1, '2', 3, 4, '5', '8']
>>> sorted(['There', 'are','some', 'sort', 'words'], key=lambda word: word.lower())
['are', 'some', 'sort', 'There', 'words']
```

Which is same as

```
sorted(['There', 'are','some', 'sort', 'words'],key=str.lower)
```

According to https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted, key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a comparison key from each list element
key=str.lower The default value is None (compare the elements directly)